# React-Leaflet Adding Heatmap Layer To Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heatmap, react-component, react-leaflet

I am having trouble fully understanding the documentation at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-heatmap-layer/v/1.0.4 to construct a heatmap layer over my leaflet map based on demographic numbers from my database. I know how to construct the code for me to display the heat map and how to format the json file from the server... there's only thing I am having a lot of trouble understanding. **How am I supposed to calculate the intensity values for each coordinate?**

Below are the examples from the documentation. The code doesn't set the "max" or "min" intensity values, so the max is set to a default of 3.0 (according to the documentation). Yet in the JSON, there are intensity values of over 500. It doesn't make sense to me:

[Example of react-leaflet map and react-leaflet-heatmap-layer layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuD7m.png)

[Example of format of json file of coordinate points for heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTSPd.png)

Does anyone have any idea how to use react-leaflet-heatmap-layer and, specifically, how I should go about calculating the intensity values? I was thinking of creating a formula to assign it a value between the min and max intensity... but it seems as if the max and min intensities do not seem to matter as seen in the example!